# GGPlot: how to change the background line and sort the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot the following graph (the example attached). What I want to achieve is to:

1-There are grey lines between Missing and power 1-1， power_1-1 and power_1-2 and so on, but no others (see the following graph). How can I have these lines between every bar in the background?

2- How can I change these lines' color (e.g., change to light blue) and line size?

3- Last, is there any way to sort my graph (through coding) based on the mean? (e.g., from -0.2231, then -0.2156, ... to 0.0592)

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c("Missing","power_1-1","power_1-2","power_1-3","power_1-4","power_1-5","power_2","power_3","power_4","power_5"),
                 mean = c(-0.0823,0.0592,-0.0556,-0.1037,-0.1303,-0.1478,-0.1857,-0.2074,-0.2231,-0.2156),
                 se = c(0.0609,0.0247,0.0216,0.0206,0.0202,0.0199,0.0194,0.0193,0.0205,0.0242), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

win.graph(width = 13,height = 6)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CI95 = list(c(mean + 1.96 * se, mean - 1.96 * se)),
         CI99 = list(c(mean + 2.58 * se, mean - 2.58 * se))) %>%
  unnest(c(CI95, CI99)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = CI99, group = id, color = id)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = CI95, group = id, color = id), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = id, y = mean, color = id), fill = "white", shape = 23, size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1:3+0.5, colour="grey70") +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: example graph is shown as the following:]

Also, is there any way to show a legend as the following:
[image]

Comment: I suspect that at least two of these questions already have answers on SO. Furthermore, multi-part questions are deprecated on SO. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c("Missing","power_1-1","power_1-2","power_1-3","power_1-4","power_1-5","power_2","power_3","power_4","power_5"),
                 mean = c(-0.0823,0.0592,-0.0556,-0.1037,-0.1303,-0.1478,-0.1857,-0.2074,-0.2231,-0.2156),
                 se = c(0.0609,0.0247,0.0216,0.0206,0.0202,0.0199,0.0194,0.0193,0.0205,0.0242), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colour_scale <- c("red", viridis::mako(9))

p1 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CI95 = list(c(mean + 1.96 * se, mean - 1.96 * se)),
         CI99 = list(c(mean + 2.58 * se, mean - 2.58 * se))) %>%
  unnest(c(CI95, CI99)) %>%
  mutate(id = factor(reorder(id, -CI99))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = CI99, group = id, color = id)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = id, y = CI95, group = id, color = id), size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = id, y = mean, color = id), fill = "white", shape = 23, size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1:9+0.5, colour="lightblue", size = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = colour_scale) +
  coord_flip()
ggsave(filename = "example_plot.png", plot = p1, width = 18, height = 6, units = "cm")
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: Many thanks. The graph is what I want, but the vertical spacing between each bar seems too large. Is there any way to reduce it? Moreover, is there any way to change the color to gradient color？ For each bar, there is no need to change the current color, but with a gradient color that looks better.

Comment: Many thanks, I have accepted it. BTW, is there any way to show the legend that is shown in my original posting?

Comment: I don't think it works that way - if you reorder the bars on the plot, you end up reordering the legend as well, sorry.